# DataGridView not updating in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Anyone got an explanation of what's going on? Changing code 1 to code 2 fixes the problem -although theoretically there should be no difference. (Theory hits practice like a pumpkin hitting a brick wall).

---

Code 1:

```
 OutputDataGridView.DataSource = myList;
```

---

Code 2:

```
 OutputDataGridView.DataSource = null;
 OutputDataGridView.DataSource = myList;
```

Comment: Where in the page's life-cycle is the datasource assigned and under what condition (if any)?

Comment: I'm creating a simple form to add a new User object to a list of User objects. Initially the DataSource is assigned to the existing list of User objects. After populating the new User object from a bunch of text fields in the form, the new object is added to the list. No update. I tried re-assigning to the same list - i.e. Code 1. No update. I changed to Code 2, and voila - it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void btnWhateverClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myGridView.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
    myGridView.DataSource = new int[0];
    myGridView.DataBind();
}
```

and you're done.

For Ref [DataSource in gridview](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/600680-objectdatasource-gridview-clear)