# DataGridView Not Updating in C# When Binding Source is Correct

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and an Edit button.  When I click the Edit button and change a field, I press Save and the DataGridView comes up again.  The problem is that my changes aren't showing.

Using the debugger, I have looked in the DGV and in the BindingSource and the correct data is there.  It is just not displaying in the DGV.

Here is my code - I do realize that it is semi-redundant but, at this point, I'm four hours into it and am willing to try anything.

```
        this.iSOXTableAdapter.FillByISOX(this.MSDataSet.ISOX);

        BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = iSOXBindingSource;
        iSOXDataGridView.DataSource = null;
        iSOXDataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
        bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        this.iSOXDataGridView.Refresh();
```

I have looked at the following questions (and many others) and tried their suggestions to no avail:

[Datagridview not updating correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519425/datagridview-not-updating-correctly)

[dataGridView not updating c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375317/datagridview-not-updating-c)

[DataGridView not updating in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858485/datagridview-not-updating-in-c-sharp)

[Best way to refresh DataGridView when you update the base data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253843/best-way-to-refresh-datagridview-when-you-update-the-base-data-source)

[How to refresh or show immediately in datagridview after inserting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299016/how-to-refresh-or-show-immediately-in-datagridview-after-inserting/30174907)

I appreciate any help or suggestions or ideas for workarounds.  Thank you so much for looking at this.

*****************  EDIT *******************

Here is the code for the save button - I know it is working because after I requery the data, it is in the binding source and in the DGV.  This code is in a separate add/edit form:

```
  private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ValidateForm())
        {
            ISOXBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender, e);
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Validated - Could not Save");
        }

    }
```

Here is full code for the user control with the DGV on it:

```
public partial class FindISOXControl : UserControl
{
    private bool gridInitialized = false;

    public delegate void ItemHasBeenSelected(object sender, SelectedItemEventArgs e);
    public event ItemHasBeenSelected SelectedItem;

    public class SelectedItemEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int SelectedChoice { get; set; }
    }

    public bool First = true;

    public FindISOXControl()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        FillTableAdapter();
        iSOXDataGridView.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().ForEach(f => f.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);

    }

    public void FillTableAdapter()
    {
        this.iSOXTableAdapter.FillByISOX(this.MSDataSet.ISO);

        BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = iSOXBindingSource;
        iSOXDataGridView.DataSource = null;
        iSOXDataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
        bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        this.iSOXDataGridView.Refresh(); 
        setGridData(); 
    }
    public void UpdateISOXText(string pISOX = "")
    {
        this.txtFind.Text = pISOX;
        txtFind.Refresh();
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
            setGridData();
        }
    }
    public void setGridData()
    {
        GetData(); 
        if (iSOXDataGridView.RowCount > 0)
        {
            EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
            iSOXDataGridView_SelectionChanged(null, e);
        }
    }
    public void txtISOX_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return || e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        {
            setGridData();
        }
    }
    //Query database
    public void GetData()
    {
        String searchValue = txtFind.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
        int rowIndex = -1;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in iSOXDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
            {
                rowIndex = row.Index;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rowIndex == -1)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in iSOXDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(searchValue))
                {
                    rowIndex = row.Index;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        if (rowIndex == -1)
        {
            if (searchValue != null && searchValue !="")
            { 
                MessageBox.Show(searchValue + " Not Found");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            iSOXDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
            iSOXDataGridView.CurrentCell = iSOXDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0];
        }

    }


    public void iSOXDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (iSOXDataGridView.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            int Row = iSOXDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index;
            if (gridInitialized)
            {
                txtFind.Text = iSOXDataGridView[0, Row].Value.ToString();
                // 6 is the ID column
                DataGridViewCellEventArgs ev = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(6, Row);
                iSOXDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(sender, ev);
            }
        }
    }
    private void iSOXDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex < iSOXDataGridView.RowCount)
        {
            // 6 == id column
            int choice = (int)iSOXDataGridView[6, First ? 0 : e.RowIndex].Value;
            this.SelectedItem(this, new SelectedItemEventArgs { SelectedChoice = choice });

        }
    }

    private void iSOXDataGridView_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // 6 is the ID column
        DataGridViewCellEventArgs ev = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(6, e.RowIndex);
        if (e.RowIndex != 0)
        {
            First = false;
            iSOXDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(sender, ev);
        }
    }
    private void iSOXDataGridView_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        { First = true; }
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the main form with the user control on it after it returns from the edit:

```
   uc.FillTableAdapter();
```

*********      EDIT --> Code that is opening Edit form:

```
            AddEditISOX aeix = new AddEditISOX("E", currentISOX);
            aeix.ShowDialog();
            ISOX_Load(sender, e);

           ISOX_Load() calls  uc.FillTableAdapter();
```

Comment: Could you post full code?

Comment: Consider posting the relevant Edit/Save button code. Posted binding code seems OK - but could be important where it is placed / when it runs.

Comment: Code is in a separate form? How are you passing your dataset instances relevant data to it?

Comment: I am sending the ID to the ADD/EDIT form. Making the changes, saving it in the Add/Edit form then requerying it when it returns from the form.

Comment: I think you need to call AcceptChanges(); on your DataTable.

Comment: I will try it :)

Comment: No luck @Berkay  The data is in the table adapter, it is just not displaying on the grid.

Comment: Have you tried setting source to null before rebind it?

Comment: Your approach seems like it **should work** (tried something similar). You should post the SaveButton code up to the part that does *TableAdapter.Update()* and the part that does *EditForm.ShowDialog*  paired with the grid's *FillTableAdapter*. Might be worth veryfing 1.If the rowStates are as expcted before update. 2. If you stop the app abruptly after the Save function finishes - will the updated data be there on a fresh start?

Comment: @Berkay -- yep - did that, too :)

Comment: @user6144226 - I did verify that the correct data was in the table while the wrong data was showing on the screen.   The Save button is an SQL statement and the Edit form does not use the same table adapter -- it uses the same table.  The correct data is in the table adapter -- it just doesn't show up.

Comment: Last suggestion. Try Datagridview.Invalidate(); after set data source.

Comment: It's unclear what you are doing/what you are asking. You code has lots of strange things like calling event handler methods directly. Just keep in mind, before saving data, you need to end current edit and apply pending changes to the underlying data source. In your case, since you are using `BindingSource`, you should call `EndEdit` method of the `BindingSource` before save: `this.Validate(); this.bindingSource1.EndEdit(); this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.myDataSet);`

Comment: Hey @Berkay - thanks but no luck there.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - Desperate times call for desperate measures.  I'm trying everything I can to get this to work.  I added your code and it didn't impact the outcome.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: Can you recreate this issue by simple data? So we can try?

Comment: Running out of reasonable ideas here. This is either some wierd transaction/connection  caching issue (unlikely). How many rows do you have? Maybe your adatper doesn't have ClearBeforeFill set - and you just see the old rows on top.

Comment: Thank you so much for thinking about this.  I do have ClearBeforeFill set and I only have around 20 rows.  I guess I can try to figure out how to redraw the current row because the data is there.

Comment: Maybe it's a thread issue, have you tried explicitly update the data in the UI thread? 
Can you try this method? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16030244/3069162
Should be relativly similar to setup.

Comment: interesting idea, @GaelSa.  I will look into that.

Comment: can you please post the code that's opening the edit form?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this @Ctznkane525

Comment: does the function you added call this - this.iSOXTableAdapter.FillByISOX(this.MSDataSet.ISOX);...are you certain its a binding source issue?...have you set a breakpoint at the refreshed dataset and used the datatable visualizer to be certain the data is in the refreshed data set?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 -- I have and the data is the refreshed data set.

Comment: what the code in ISOXBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click and AddEditISOX if you code make a small repro on git that would help

Comment: I feel fairly certain that the save button and the add edit buttons are working.  The data is there -- it is just not refreshing -- even if refresh is called.  At this point, I think the only options are to to redraw the current row from the data source or redraw the grid with the existing data in the data source (because it is right -- just the grid is wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this blasted thing out.  In my Edit Button Click method, I need to call the user control fill table adapter method again.

```
     private void BtnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentISOX != 0)
        {
            AddEditISO aei = new AddEditISOX("E", currentISOX);
            aei.ShowDialog();
            findISOXControl1.FillTableAdapter(); 

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Make a Selection First");
        }
    }
```

Thanks for everyone's thoughts, advice and input.  It was very helpful and eventually led me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

A DataGridView sets up bindings the first time you assign the DataSource. The problem is that subsequent DataSource assignments, if the assignments have a different structure from the initial assignment, will fail because the bindings are now "off"

You need to reset the DataGridView [thusly](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/256055/how-to-reset-a-datagridview) so that the data is bound a new. (The link is for VB but you just need to know the methods to call. Even copy/paste would be overkill.)

Comment: I don't know if it's different for other .net versions but for 4.6.1 which i use, i never reset the datagridview. and the bindings are allways different on only one control. and it works

Comment: The link doesn't show the answer :(   It says This topic has been dead for over six months.    Can you post the answer you found?  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have proper update sql commands in the adapter 
add these commands to your intialize method

```
iSOXTableAdapter.Adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.Error;
iSOXTableAdapter.Adapter.MissingMappingAction = MissingMappingAction.Error;
```

maybe the generated error will tell you what are you missing there

Answer (score 1):

bind your data to the View of table and it would automatically get updates.

Comment: Not so much -- the data is bound and it is still not working.  Thanks for thinking of this.  I will review my code again though.